# Subscription History

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of `user_ids`, `subscription_tier`, `activity_date` (which is each date the user was active). How would I construct a table which would for each user show their movement and dates between tiers.

Using `Min(activity_date)` and `Max(activity_date)` would only work if the user didn't move to a tier they had previously been at. Where the reality is people upgrade and downgrade all the time.

What I want to create is a table with the columns `user_id`, `subscription_tier`, `tier_start_date`, `tier_end_date`.

Comment: Agreed. Want to put a table but not sure how

Comment: is the subscription_tier table a snapshot of the current state?

Comment: So for every time they log on a new row appears which gives the id, the tier state and date. If they upgrade, then the next time they use the service it will give the new tier, existing id and date

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `lead()?

```
select user_id, subscription_tier, activity_date as tier_start_date,
       lead(activity_date) over (partition by user_id order by activity_date) as tier_end_date
from t;
```